# I dont understand this lines of code. Can you say me the logic?

Tags: python

Its about encrypting

```
def encrypt(plain_text, shift_amount):
    cipher_text = ""
    for letter in plain_text:
        position = alphabet.index(letter)
        new_position = position + shift_amount
        new_letter = alphabet[new_position]
        cipher_text += new_letter
    print(f"The encoded text is {cipher_text}")
```

I don't understand logic of `def encrypt`. Thank you. I am new on Python.
Example I don't understand why we create `cipher_text` or why we write `position`.

I didn't put the beginning and continuation of the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [do your research first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). The web has lots of introductory Python tutorials. We'd be happy to help you once you have a *specific* question that you can't find an answer to even after reading up on it first. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The full code likely looks like this with an alphabet list and is a simple function to implement a [Caesar Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).  I've commented the full code below for an explanation of what each line is attempting to do:

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"] # list of letters

def encrypt(plain_text, shift_amount):
    cipher_text = "" # setup a blank string
    for letter in plain_text: # for each letter in the word you want to encode
        position = alphabet.index(letter) # check the numeric position of that letter in the alphabet starting from 0 i.e. a = 0, z = 25 as it starts from 0 not 1
        new_position = position + shift_amount # the position is then added to the shift_amount which is called a Caesar cypher https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher
        new_letter = alphabet[new_position] # use this new 'index' number to get the new character
        cipher_text += new_letter # add that new letter to the string and then return to the beginning to get the next letter
    print(f"The encoded text is {cipher_text}") # print out the newly "shifted" or encrypted word

encrypt("hello", 1)
# The encoded text is ifmmp
```